# Powershell V5 SQL Agent job receives: Read-SQLTableData is not recognized

Tags: powershell, sql-agent

I get the following error when running Powershell in a SQL Agent job:

> The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'The term
>   'Read-SQLTableData' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.  '.  Process Exit Code -1.

The step works when running in Powershell ISE itself and I have recently upgraded to Powershell V5.

When I run "$psversiontable" in the SQL Agent jobstep it returns:

> PSVersion 5.1.14409.1018

"Get-Command -Name *SQL*TableData"  retruns:

```
  Read-SqlTableData               Write-SQlTableData
```

I also updated  dbo.syssubsystems  but all the Poweshell executables appear to be V1, does this matter?